# How to handle date like 00000000(yyyyMMdd) in Dataframe scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to scala,I have test.csv file,I'm able to read dataframe but i have a DATE column in csv file it contains date like "00000000".How can i handle the date like "00000000".
If date like "00000000" How can i replace with null.Any help will be appreciated.

test.csv

```
TYPE,CODE,SQ_CODE,RE_TYPE,VERY_ID,IN_DATE,DATE
"F","000544","2017002","OP","95032015062763298","20150610","00000000"
"F","000544","2017002","LD","95032015062763261","20150611","20150519"
"F","000544","2017002","AK","95037854336743246","20150611","20150429"   

 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("IT_DATA").getOrCreate()


          //Create dataframe boject
            val df = sparkSession.read
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
            .option("location", "/xx/xx/xx/xx/test.csv") 
            .option("delimiter", ",")
            .option("dateFormat", "yyyyMMdd")
            .load().cache()

df.printSchema
root
 |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SQ_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- RE_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VERY_ID: long (nullable = true)
 |-- IN_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- DATE: date (nullable = true)

df.show
```

Actual output

```
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
| TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE|      DATE   |
+-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 20150610|   0002-11-30|
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 20150611|   2015-05-19|
|   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 20150611|   2015-04-29|
+-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
```

expected output

```
    +-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
    | TYPE|   CODE|  SQ_CODE| RE_TYPE |            VERY_ID|  IN_DATE|      DATE   |
    +-----+-------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
    |   F | 000544|  2017002|      OP |  95032015062763298| 20150610|        null |
    |   F | 000544|  2017002|      LD |  95032015062763261| 20150611|   2015-05-19|
    |   F | 000544|  2017002|      AK |  95037854336743246| 20150611|   2015-04-29|
    +-----+-------+---------+--+------+-------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"00000000" is a valid date format according to your dateFormat.  So there is no way spark can see this as a null unless you change the "null" value.

In csv reader, you can specify it:

```
nullValue (default empty string): sets the string representation of a null value. Since 2.0.1, this applies to all supported types including the string type.
```

You could apply a transformation to the DF to transform it back to null when is falls outside valid range

```
val df = List((1,"0000"), (2, "12345")).toDF("id", "value")
df.withColumn("value", when(df("value") === "0000", null).otherwise(df("value"))).show
```

Since your dates are already parsed to some values, you can filter them using simple functions like this:

```
df.withColumn("date", when(year(df("date")) < 1900, null).otherwise(df("value"))).show
```

Comment: thanks for your reply could you tell me how can I "00000000" to null transform in DF side only.

Comment: If i will use actual dataframe to compare the date then this logic will not work   df.withColumn("DATE", when(df("DATE") === "00000000", null).otherwise(df("DATE"))).show

Comment: My example was on the string version before parsing dates..  but you could do about the same logic for dates